# Twelve Months in one view in Material-UI calendar- DatePicker or Any other package

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, calendar, next.js

I'm doing a calendar project in nextjs. I want a 12 month view calendar.

Is there anyway to get 12 months view calendar in Material UI? https://mui.com/api/date-picker/

Or Can anyone suggest a calendar with can do 12 months view

I need like this 12 months calendar
https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/calendar_2017_design_with_months_illustration_on_squares_6824047.jpg

Comment: Have a look at the picker [sub-components](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#sub-components).

Comment: @NearHuscarl I looked that. There is no like 12 moths view. I need 12 months in one view

Answer (score 1):

This particular layout is currently unavailable with Material-UI. However, you can use [react-yearly-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-yearly-calendar).

I've used this package a few times, it works well.

[image]